# Hibernate Error - clause referenced two different from-clause elements

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to join 3 tables in an entity class...But I am getting the following error when I am trying to build it. Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong in the query..........

The class  which I have written is  given below:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString(callSuper = true)
@Entity
@Table( name = "change_request", schema = "ssp" )
public class ChangeRequest extends CommonEntity {

    @Id
    @Column( name = "change_request_number" )
    private String changeRequestNumber;

    @ToString.Exclude
    @OneToMany( cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "changeRequest" )
    private Set<ChangeRequestFieldValue> fieldValues = new LinkedHashSet<>();
....
    @Column( name = "lock_time" )
    private Date lockTime;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    @JoinColumn(name = "change_request_id")
    private RouterChangeRequestRelation routerChangeRequestRelation;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    @JoinColumn( name = "router_id")
    private Router router;

    public boolean addChangeRequestValue( ChangeRequestFieldValue value ) {
        value.setChangeRequest( this );
        return fieldValues.add( value );
    }

    public boolean addAttachment( ChangeRequestAttachment value ) {
        value.setChangeRequest( this );
        return attachments.add( value );
    }

}
```

---

I have added the query in th Repo class

```
  @Query( "SELECT cr FROM ChangeRequest cr " +
            "INNER JOIN cr.routerChangeRequestRelation rcr WITH rcr.changeRequestId = cr.changeRequestNumber " +
            "INNER JOIN rcr.router r WITH rcr.routerId = r.routerId " +
            "WHERE cr.archivedBy IS NULL AND (cr.assignee IN :userNames OR cr.createdBy IN :userNames) AND cr.plant.plant IN :plants " +
            "AND :filters " +
            "GROUP BY cr.changeRequestNumber ORDER BY cr.createdDate DESC" )
    Page<ChangeRequest> findOpenChangeRequestsByCreatorOrAssigneeFromPlants( @Param( "userNames" ) List<String> userNames,
                                                                             @Param( "plants" ) List<String> plants,
                                                                             @Param( "filters" ) String filters,
                                                                             Pageable pageable);

}
```

---

The error when doing mvn clean install:

```
17:45:05.422 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect - HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL94Dialect
17:45:05.565 [main] INFO  o.h.e.j.e.i.LobCreatorBuilderImpl - HHH000424: Disabling contextual LOB creation as createClob() method threw error : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
17:45:05.565 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry - HHH000270: Type registration [java.util.UUID] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.UUIDBinaryType@2f356178
17:45:05.782 [main] INFO  o.s.o.j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean - Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
17:45:07.809 [main] INFO  o.h.h.i.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator - HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
17:45:08.505 [main] ERROR o.h.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter -  with-clause referenced two different from-clause elements
17:45:08.506 [main] ERROR o.h.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter -  with-clause referenced two different from-clause elements
antlr.SemanticException: with-clause referenced two different from-clause elements
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.handleWithFragment(HqlSqlWalker.java:455)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.createFromJoinElement(HqlSqlWalker.java:403)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.joinElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3912)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3698)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElementList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3576)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:716)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:572)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:309)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:257)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:262)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:190)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:142)
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:115)
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:76)
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:150)
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:302)
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:240)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1894)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:291)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor148.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:347)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy213.createQuery(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:86)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.<init>(SimpleJpaQuery.java:62)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory.fromMethodWithQueryString(JpaQueryFactory.java:72)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory.fromQueryAnnotation(JpaQueryFactory.java:53)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$DeclaredQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:144)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:212)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:77)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:435)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:220)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:280)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:266)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:92)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDepe
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a too old version of Hibernate. You should upgrade. I think this issue was fixed in some 5.2.x version.